# Style or Prevent iOS default <select> behavior

Tags: html, ios, css, uipickerview

Perhaps I've been searching for the wrong thing but I've not been able to find a solution of how to either style or disable the default way that browsers on iOS handle `<select>`. I know when you're actually developing for iOS applications it's called a UIPickerView. Whenever I search for this I always get links to app development help.

Is any one aware of a way to handle this?

The problem that we are having is that our security questions, on our form, are too long to see.

Note: The screen shot is not of our site. I was just trying to provide an image of that to which I was referring.

[image: iOS UIPickerView in browsers]

Comment: Nope. you are stuck with the UIPickerView unless you build a custom interface using something other than a `<select>` element

Comment: Well that's not happy :(

Comment: Use checkboxes? #easysolvethings